# JSON Getting the value of a list based on the parameter

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have to process a complex JSON-file and I'm hitting some obstacles.

Below you will find a little excerpt from the class which is in XML but which I convert to JSON to be able to process it easier.

```
<Selection Category="M43002NN">
                            <ReferendumOptionIdentifier>foo</ReferendumOptionIdentifier>
                            <ValidVotes>6162</ValidVotes>
                            <CountMetric Id="M" Type="LevelDepositList">43002</CountMetric> 
                            <CountMetric Id="S4" Type="SeatsToBeFilled">23</CountMetric>    
                            <CountMetric Id="S5" Type="SubstitutesMax">0</CountMetric>      
                            <CountMetric Id="S9" Type="LinguisticRegime">2</CountMetric>                            
                            <CountMetric Id="S10" Type="VotesDeposited">6620</CountMetric>
                            <CountMetric Id="S11" Type="BlankAndInvalidVotes">458</CountMetric>
                            <CountMetric Id="S12" Type="Alderman">0</CountMetric>
                            <CountMetric Id="S14" Type="ValidVote_E5">0</CountMetric>
                            <CountMetric Id="S15" Type="BlankAndInvalidVotes_E5">0</CountMetric>    

                        </Selection>
```

In the above example I'm trying to extract the value of the CountMetric which has the type "SeatsToBeFilled".

So far I was able to collect the results and to isolate the correct CountMetric but I can't seem to get it's value.

This is my class:

```
public class TotalSelectionClass
        {
            [JsonProperty("@Category")]
            public string Category { get; set; }
            public int ValidVotes { get; set; }
            public List<CountMetricClass> CountMetric { get; set; }
        }
```

And this is the CountMetricClass that I use:

```
public class CountMetricClass
        {
            [JsonProperty("@Id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("@Type")]
            public string Type { get; set; }   

        }
```

Below is the code that I use to get the desired CountMetric (slightly reduced code for readability-purposes):

```
var TotalSeats = Selection[0].CountMetric.Where(x => x.Type == "SeatsToBeFilled").First();
```

This returns the CountMetric-object to me but how do I extract the value from it? So in this case, how do I extract the number 23 from it?

Thank you.

Comment: What you get if you try the following?: var TotalSeats = Selection[0].CountMetric.Where(x => x.Type == "SeatsToBeFilled").First().Value<int>();

Comment: I get an error message stating that the CountMetricClass does not contain a definition for value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here really depends on the shape of your JSON and, thus, how you're doing your XML -> JSON conversion. You have not provided the JSON form nor asked for help in converting the XML -> JSON so I'll answer based on the information available.

As-is, you can't get the CountMetric value from your CountMetricClass. This is because the value held in the XML (looks like 23 for SeatsToBeFilled) is never read into that object. To get the value, you'll need to

1) check that your XML converter is actually encoding the value from the XML into the JSON to be parsed

2) modify your CountMetricClass so that it's reading from this value field. I've chosen to call this field `MetricValue` for readability, but you could obviously choose whatever name works best for you. For instance, your new class may take the form of something like:

```
public class CountMetricClass
    {
        [JsonProperty("@Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("@Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }   

        [JsonProperty("@MetricValue")]
        public int MetricValue { get; set; }
    }
```

3) once we've successfully read the MetricValue into your CountMetricClass, we can modify your linq expression to get the value by accessing the MetricValue field from the target CountMetric like:

```
var TotalSeats = Selection[0].CountMetric.Where(x => x.Type == "SeatsToBeFilled").MetricValue;
```

Comment: Thank you @Sirhamy for having a look at my problem. I've looked up the actual JSON that is being generated by NewtonSoft.Json and this is what I get: {"@Id":"S4","@Type":"SeatsToBeFilled","#text":"23"}

Answer (score 0):

A little follow-up for those who might run into the same issue.

Based on SIRHAMY's suggestion I had a look at the actual JSON which I was converting from XML.

```
{"@Id":"S4","@Type":"SeatsToBeFilled","#text":"23"}
```

As SIRHAMY suggested I created a Text-field in my CountMetricClass

```
public class CountMetricClass
        {
            [JsonProperty("@Id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("@Type")]
            public string Type { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("#Text")]
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }
```

After that I could get the value of the text by using:

```
Selection[0].CountMetric.Where(x => x.Type == "SeatsToBeFilled").First().Text
```

This will return "23" to me.

Thank you SIRHAMY!